# Python - How can I install xlutils?

Tags: python, excel

I am using Python 2.5 (and need to stay with that) and have already downloaded xlrd 0.8.0 and xlwt 0.7.2, and they both seem to be working OK.

I will be needing to read from and write to Excel spreadsheets, and so believe I will need to add xlutils as well.  The problem is, I can't install it so far.

I have pip and tried the simple:

```
pip install xlutils
```

That ran and downloaded xlutils, but got hung up with:

```
Downloading/unpacking xlutils
  Downloading xlutils-1.6.0.tar.gz (54Kb): 54Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package xlutils
Downloading/unpacking xlrd>=0.7.2 (from xlutils)
  Downloading xlrd-0.9.2.tar.gz (167Kb): 167Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package xlrd
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.6.0\build\xlrd\setup.py", li
ne 8, in <module>
        raise Exception("This version of xlrd requires Python 2.6 or above. "
    Exception: This version of xlrd requires Python 2.6 or above. For older versions of Python, you can use the 0.8 series.
... [snipping some]
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Python25\Lib\sit
e-packages\xlutils-1.6.0\build\xlrd
```

So then I figured it was trying to download a newer xlrd (which I *can't use* with Python 2.5) and since I already have xlrd installed, it breaks on that.

I then tried to just download xlutils from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils, and then unzipped it with 7zip, put the xlutils folder under Python25>Lib>site-packages, cd'd there, and did:

```
python setup.py install
```

but that gives me this error in the cmd window:

```
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\xlutils-1.6.0>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

**So how can I install this?**

Comment: use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) and use a decent version of python!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you do not *need* `xlutils` just to read and write Excel files.  You can read them with `xlrd` and write them with `xlwt` and provide your own "glue" in the Python code that you write yourself.

That said, `xlutils` does provide features that make some things more convenient than writing them for yourself (that is the point of its existence).  So the second part of my answer is:  You do not need to "install" `xlutils` per se.  You can just unpack it and put the `xlutils` directory into `site-packages` and be off and running.  This is true for pretty much every pure-Python package, as far as I know.  (Some other packages are partially written in C (or sometimes other languages) and these often require specific installation steps.)  So why do pure-Python packages provide a `setup.py` script?  Usually to run tests or to build `.pyc` files, both of which are optional.

Comment: Great, just putting it there does work.  I've never quite known why I couldn't do this in most cases, and you've answered that.  Also, thanks for the point about *needing* xlutils.  Great answer overall.

Answer (score 2):

xlutils 1.4.1 is compatible with python 2.5. So this should work:

```
pip install xlutils==1.4.1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried that (correcting the typo to xlutils not xlutis) but got the same error:  "Exception: This version of xlrd requires Python 2.6 or above. For older versions of Python, you can use the 0.8 series."

Comment: That's because you are still having the new version. Try uninstalling xlutils first with 'pip uninstall xlutils' and installing it again.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.  And I don't think it ever got installed, since I can't import it.  In any case, I'm going to just put the folder there myself, as in John Y's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try install python-setuptools package.

In Debian: 
`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

For 3.x version

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 install xlutils`

Using pip3 instead of pip solved it for me.